# .htaccess redirect don't render page properly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am facing a wired issue.. 
during maintenance time, i tried to redirect all request to maintenance page. (maintenance.html).

But the problem is when i visit that page directly it shows properly (honor css/styles) but when htaccess/server redirect to that page it doesn't show/honor the styles :(

i have searched here and some one told to change css path from "css/styles.css" to "/css/styles.css" but that even didn't work :(

here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

Here is how it looks when i visit the page directly:
[image]

And Here what it looks like if it is redirected by server/.htaccess file:
[image]

i hope that makes sense and also that's not very hard to solve.. all i just can't figure it out :(

Comment: And you tagged this with `css` and `html` for what reason?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, sorry for that, but those 2 tag was suggestged by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ignoring css/js/images from your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ maintenance.html [R=307,L,NC]
```

Comment: i also notice you have change my last line too? from "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [R=307,L]" to "RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ maintenance.html [R=307,L,NC]", can you tell me what's the difference?

Comment: It just combined your condition into `RewriteRule`. It just means if URI is not `maintenance.html` then route to `maintenance.html`. Did it work?

Comment: thanks a lot for the clearance, but i am sorry i didn't try that yet, as that will make my server unavailable while many workers are working right now.. however,i will test in few minutes and will update you. thanks again...